# How do I call a directive's method when there are multiple instances of directive in same template?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I have a navbar with multiple dropdown menus. I'm using a directive provided by ngx-bootstrap to handle dropdown behavior. I want to add custom functionality by opening the dropdowns on mouseover and closing them on mouseout. I need to call the BsDropdownToggleDirective's onEsc() function on mouseout. When I implement this with @ViewChild, it works only for the first dropdown, but not the second. When I remove the first dropdown, then the second dropdown works. How can I call onEsc() for whichever dropdown is open?

**top-menu-links.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDropdownToggleDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

@Component({
    selector: 'top-nav-main',
    templateUrl: './top-menu-links.component.html',
    // styleUrls: [ './top-menu-links.component.scss' ]
})
export class TopMenuLinksComponent {
    @ViewChild(BsDropdownToggleDirective) dropdown:BsDropdownToggleDirective;

    public closeDropdown():void {
        this.dropdown.onEsc();
    }

}
```

**top-menu-links.component.html**

```
<li class="dropdown" bsDropdown triggers="mouseover" >
                <a bsDropdownToggle dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" (mouseout)="closeDropdown()">Features<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" *bsDropdownMenu>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="feature-1">Feature 1</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="feature-2">Feature 2</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="feature-3">Feature 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown" bsDropdown triggers="mouseover">
                <a bsDropdownToggle dropdown-toggle data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" (mouseout)="closeDropdown()">Company<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" *bsDropdownMenu>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="app-about-us">About</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="app-faq">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="app-contact-us">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: You have to use [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-decorator.html) instead of @ViewChild

Comment: When I change ViewChild to ViewChildren, I get TypeError: this.dropdown.onEsc is not a function. Do I have to do something else to make ViewChildren work?

Comment: why are you using `directive` **explicitly**

Comment: You are missing to iterate over the childrens. I put an example as an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned above, you have to use @ViewChildren decorator. Please give a try with this:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDropdownToggleDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';

@Component({
    selector: 'top-nav-main',
    templateUrl: './top-menu-links.component.html',
    // styleUrls: [ './top-menu-links.component.scss' ]
})
export class TopMenuLinksComponent {
    @ViewChildren(BsDropdownToggleDirective) dropdowns: QueryList<BsDropdownToggleDirective>;

    public closeDropdown():void {
        this.dropdowns.forEach((dropdown) => {
          dropdown.onEsc()
       })
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The @Directive provides an "exportAs" property to then reference your directive from the template.

```js
@Directive({
 selector: '[BsDropdownToggleDirective]',
 exportAs: 'bsDropdown' // <- add the name you want here
})
```

Then within your template, you can create an element reference using the # notation, i.e.

```html
<div #theDropdown="bsDropdown">Hello</div>
```

Which means you should then be able to use @ViewChild in your controller

```js
@ViewChild("theDropdown")
dropDown: BsDropdownToggleDirective;
```

And as you have a reference in the template as well, you might use it directly in the template as well:

```html
<div #theDropdown="bsDropdown">Hello</div>
<button (click)="bsDropdown.onEsc()">Close drop down</button>
```

Comment: As a side comment, you can check this free lesson on exportAs: https://ultimatecourses.com/learn/angular-pro#:~:text=Using%20the%20exportAs%20property%20with%20template%20refs